# performance of visibilityOfElementLocated v/s presenceOfElementLocated (selenium webdriver - Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I prefer using `visibilitOfElementLocated` to locate elements over `presenceOfElementLocated`.
The reason for this is it does the work of `presenceOfElementLocated` as well (Correct me if i'm wrong).

But there were few situations where i could've achieved my goal just by using `presenceOfElementLocated`, instead i used `visibilityOfElementLocated`.

**Question :**

- will this effect the performance(time) of my code?

(or let me rephrase)

- will the performance(time) improve if i change appropriate one's to `presenceOfElementLocated`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would guess that `presenceOfElementLocated` will be slighty faster because it's just check elements presence on the page while the `visibilityOfElementLocated` has to check the presence **and** whether is element visible.

But I think it really doesn't matter from the performance perspective (what's the point if you save 0.001 second during this checking?), you better choose appropriate method depending on your use case.

- use `presenceOfElementLocated` when you don't care whether if element visible or not, you just need to know if it's on the page
- use `visibilityOfElementLocated` when you need to find element which should be also visible

Look at the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for more info.